# Comparing the instances between two objects. C++

Tags: c++, object, compare, instance

I am currently creating a poorly designed game of Battleship, and I have reached a spot I cant exactly figure out how to access some data from another object.

I have a board class which creates two arrays with a size of 100. I have a player class that has an instance of the two boards belonging to them (their board, and enemy board(hit,miss,empty))

What I'm having trouble doing, is figuring out how to make the two players boards sync up but within a function for board, inside player...

My functions are suppose to be off the board so that

```
 class Board{
    int playerBoard[100];
    int enemyBoard[100];

    int makeMove(Move)
      {
        // compare player1.enemyBoard to player2.playerBoard (THIS ??)
      };

 class Player{
    Board playerBoards;

    void makeMove() // edit, the makeMove() in players, cant have parameters
    {
    playerBoards.makeMove(Move x){...};
    };
 }

 Player player1;
 Player player2;

player1.makeMove(Move x);
```

But how do I get to player2, while inside the functions of player1.boards ...
Im confused, and any help would be greatly appreciated. And Im sorry for any confusion this may cause.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement like the following solution

```
class Board{
      private:
        int player1Board[100];
        int player2Board[100];
      public:
        int* getPlayerBoard(int playerID){
            if (playerID == 1)
                 return &player1Board;
            else if (playerID == 2)
                 return &player2Board;
            else
                 return nullptr;
        }
        int makeMove(Move,int playerID)
        {
           if(playerID == 1){
              //update player1Board
           }
           elseif (playerID == 2){
              //update player2Board
           }
       };

class Player{
    private:
       Board* playerBoards;
       int playerID;

    public:
       Player(int _playerID, Board* _playerBoards){
          playerID = _playerID;
          playerBoards = _playerBoards;
       }
       void makeMove() // edit, the makeMove() in players, cant have parameters
       {
          playerBoards->makeMove(Move x,playerID){...};
       };        
 }

 Board playerBoards;
 Player player1(1,&playerBoards);
 Player player2(2,&playerBoards);

 player1.makeMove(Move x);
```

to improve it further you can use singleton pattern for the class Board as well